# Add query values to an asp Link Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I have this Link Button here.

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server" Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl='<%# "./DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=MyPDF" %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

And it doesn't work, it says "could not find file". I know it's the query string because when I put the path to the file manually, it works like a charm.

I have also tried this:

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server" Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl='<%# "./DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=" + Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click"
    runat="server" Text="My PDF"    
    NavigateUrl="~/DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=MyPDF">
  </asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

Comment: This didnt work...is there something I used be using in my code behind?

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong string, I've updated it. You might want to hover over the generated link and check the url that it generates.

Comment: tried that too and it didnt work, I still get the same error :( I am calling it in my code behind as `Request.QueryString["filename"]`

Comment: in your codebehind, if you place a breakpoint after the String myFileName = (String)Request.QueryString["filename"] line, do you get the correct value in the myFileName variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
<asp:HyperLink ... NavigateUrl='<%# "DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=" +  Eval("ID") %>' />
```

The LinkButton Control has no property "NavigateUrl". this control just can do a post back for you, if you need link directly to another location use HyperLink instead.

Comment: This has just changed my link into static text....`<asp:HyperLink ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server" Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl='<%# "DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=" +  Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>`

Comment: plus that takes away my onclick event

Comment: you cannot use OnClick and NavigateUrl at the same time. when user click on the link , you can handle by serverside OnClick event and the redirect user after some operations

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server" Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl="./DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename="+'<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

Comment: That gives me a new error `The server tag is not well formed.`

Answer (score 0):

User the CommandArgument property in the LinkButton

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" runat="server" Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl='<%# GetUrl(Eval("Id")) %>'></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

and then add into a codebehind something like this:

```
protected string GetUrl(string id) { return ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename={0}", id)); }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<li>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="MyPDF" OnClick="Download_Click" runat="server"
    Text="My PDF" NavigateUrl="DownloadableProducts.aspx?filename=<%#Eval("ID") %>" >   
  </asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

this will work